# How to use map-function in SPARK with Java

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

I try to read a csv-file in spark and I want to split the lines, which are comma-seperated, so that I have an RDD with a two dimensional Array. I am very new to Spark.

I tried to do this:

```
public class SimpleApp 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {       
        String master = "local[2]";
        String csvInput = "/home/userName/Downloads/countrylist.csv";
        String csvOutput = "/home/userName/Downloads/countrylist";

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(master, "loadwholecsv", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), System.getenv("JARS"));

        JavaRDD<String> csvData = sc.textFile(csvInput, 1);
        JavaRDD<String> words = csvData.map(new Function <List<String>>() { //line 43
              @Override
              public List<String> call(String s) {
                return Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
              }
            });

        words.saveAsTextFile(csvOutput);
    }
}
```

This should split the lines and return an ArrayList. But I am not sure about this.
I get this error:

```
SimpleApp.java:[43,58] wrong number of type arguments; required 2
```

Comment: You need to add the input type argument too: `new Function <String, List<String>>()`

Comment: BTW, you most probably want to use `flatMap` and `FlatMapFunction` (http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~pwendell/strataconf/api/core/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html).

Comment: btw2, you should learn some Scala. Makes using Spark so much easier: `csvData.map(line => line.split("\\s*,\\s*"))`

Comment: thank you all! @maasg: I do this for an university project, where i have to use java.

Comment: @maasg Probably flatMap is still a good idea. ;) `csvData.flatMap(line => line.split("\\s*,\\s*"))` (Unless the result should be RDD[Array[String]].)

Comment: @GáborBakos sure if the intention is to have separated words. Following the question, the OP wants the splitted lines "so that i have an RDD with a two dimensional Array" -- in any case,  Scala is a good idea :-) :-)

Comment: hello @GáborBakos sir.. can you explain the difference between Map() and flatMap()?

Comment: @satish Unfortunately I am not so good at explaining things, probably you can find good tutorials by searching through the internet. Basically from a list<a> with a function a->list<a> map generates a list<list<a>>, while flatMap flattens the inner lists and it becomes just a list<a>.

Comment: @BdEngineer No idea what you want to do there. Do you want to [`join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#join-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-) the two datasets? Or [`crossJoin`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#crossJoin-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So there are a two small issues with the program. First is you probably want flatMap rather than map, since you are trying to return an RDD of words rather than an RDD of Lists of words, we can use flatMap to flatten the result. The other is, our function class also requires the type of the input it is called on. I'd replace the JavaRDD words... with:

```
JavaRDD<String> words = rdd.flatMap(
  new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() { public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
      return Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    }});
```

Comment: Thanks, but its my fault! I want to create an RDD of Lists of words. I fixed it now with @Gábor Bakos comment. Also i changd JavaRDD<String> to JavaRDD<List<String>>

Comment: Oh rad. In that case yah just do

Comment: how can we return an rdd of vector?

Comment: @Holden could you please advice what is wrong here in reduce function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843599/reduce-result-datasets-into-single-dataset

Answer (score 2):

This is the sample of code from https://opencredo.com/data-analytics-using-cassandra-and-spark/ tutorial in Java.

Scala code :

```
  /* 1*/    val includedStatuses = Set("COMPLETED", "REPAID")
/* 2*/    val now = new Date();
/* 3*/    sc.cassandraTable("cc", "cc_transactions")
/* 4*/      .select("customerid", "amount", "card", "status", "id")
/* 5*/      .where("id < minTimeuuid(?)", now)
/* 6*/      .filter(includedStatuses contains _.getString("status"))
/* 7*/      .keyBy(row => (row.getString("customerid"), row.getString("card")))
/* 8*/      .map { case (key, value) => (key, value.getInt("amount")) }
/* 9*/      .reduceByKey(_ + _)
/*10*/      .map { case ((customerid, card), balance) => (customerid, card, balance, now) }
/*11*/      .saveToCassandra("cc", "cc_balance", SomeColumns("customerid", "card", "balance", "updated_at"))
```

Java code :

```
SparkContextJavaFunctions functions = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(ProjectPropertie.context);
        JavaRDD<Balance> balances = functions.cassandraTable(ProjectPropertie.KEY_SPACE, Transaction.TABLE_NAME)
                .select("customerid", "amount", "card", "status", "id")
                .where("id < minTimeuuid(?)", date)
                .filter( row -> row.getString("status").equals("COMPLETED") )
                .keyBy(row -> new Tuple2<>(row.getString("customerid"), row.getString("card")))
                .mapToPair( row -> new Tuple2<>(row._1,row._2.getInt("amount")))
                .reduceByKey( (i1,i2) -> i1.intValue()+i2.intValue())
                .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, Integer>, Balance>() {

                    /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public Iterator<Balance> call(Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, Integer> r) throws Exception {
                        List<Balance> list = new ArrayList<Balance>();
                        list.add(new Balance(r._1._1, r._1._2, r._2,reportDate));
                        return list.iterator();
                    }
                }).cache();
```

Where `ProjectPropertie.context` is `SparkContext`
Here is how you can get SparkContext (only one context per JVM you should use):

```
   SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName("App_name").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
                            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1,172.17.0.2")
                            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
                            .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")
                            .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra");
   SparkContext context = new SparkContext(conf);
```

For datasource I'm using Cassandra, where 172.17.0.2 is docker container where my Cassandra node is running and 127.0.0.1 is the host (in this case is local)

Comment: could you please advice what is wrong here in reduce function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843599/reduce-result-datasets-into-single-dataset

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do...

```
        //======Using flatMap(RDD of words)==============
       JavaRDD<String> csvData = spark.textFile(GlobalConstants.STR_INPUT_FILE_PATH, 1);
        JavaRDD<String> counts = csvData.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
          //line 43
              @Override
              public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
                return Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
              }
            });     

    //======Using map(RDD of Lists of words)==============
        JavaRDD<String> csvData = spark.textFile(GlobalConstants.STR_INPUT_FILE_PATH, 1);
        JavaRDD<List<String>> counts = csvData.map(new Function <String, List<String>>() { //line 43
              @Override
              public List<String> call(String s) {
                return Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
              }
            }); 

    //=====================================

    counts.saveAsTextFile(GlobalConstants.STR_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH);
```

Comment: could you please advice what is wrong here in reduce function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843599/reduce-result-datasets-into-single-dataset