# reduce result datasets into single dataset

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1version with java8

I have a scenario where i have to collect/reduce calculated datasets into common/result dataset, but i am getting an error

**Below is the code snippet :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<String[]> stringAsList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringAsList.add(new String[] { "6","7","8" ,"A" });
        stringAsList.add(new String[] { "82","72","58","A" });
        stringAsList.add(new String[] { "63","17","18","B" });
        stringAsList.add(new String[] { "16","70","81","A" });
        stringAsList.add(new String[] { "69","34","8","B" });
        stringAsList.add(new String[] { "82","72","58","A" });
        stringAsList.add(new String[] { "63","17","18","B" });
        stringAsList.add(new String[] { "16","70","81","A" });
        stringAsList.add(new String[] { "69","34","8","B" });
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

        JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(stringAsList).map((String[] row) -> RowFactory.create(row));

       
        StructType schema = DataTypes
                .createStructType(new StructField[] {
                        DataTypes.createStructField("code1", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("code2", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("code3", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("class", DataTypes.StringType, false)
                      
                });

        Dataset<Row> dataDf= spark.sqlContext().createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema).toDF();

Dataset<Row> data= dataDf
                .withColumn("code1", col("code1").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType))
                .withColumn("code2", col("code2").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType))
                .withColumn("code3", col("code3").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType))
                  .withColumn("class", col("class").cast(DataTypes.StringType))
                  ;


//data.show();
List<String> interestedCols = Arrays.asList("code1","code3");

// reduced final result dataset 
Dataset<Row> resultDs = interestedCols.stream().reduce(data, dataAccumlator, datasetCombiner);

resultDs.show();

System.out.println("Done");

}



Dataset<Row> dataAccumlator(Dataset<Row> df, String coll) {
        Dataset<Row> dd = df.groupBy("class").agg( avg(coll).alias("mean"), expr("percentile("+ coll + ", array(0.5, 0.4, 0.1) )").alias("percentiles"));

        return dd
        .withColumn("per50", col("percentiles").getItem(0) )
        .withColumn("coll", lit(coll));
    }

Dataset<Row> datasetCombiner(Dataset<Row> left, Dataset<Row> right) {
        return left.union(right);
    }
```

**Given Input Data :**

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|code1|code2|code3|class|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    6|    7|    8|    A|
|   82|   72|   58|    A|
|   63|   17|   18|    B|
|   16|   70|   81|    A|
|   69|   34|    8|    B|
|   82|   72|   58|    A|
|   63|   17|   18|    B|
|   16|   70|   81|    A|
|   69|   34|    8|    B|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

**Expected output**

```
+-----+----+------------------+-----+-----+
|class|mean|       percentiles|per50| coll|
+-----+----+------------------+-----+-----+
|    B|66.0|[66.0, 64.2, 63.0]| 66.0|code1|
|    A|40.4|[16.0, 16.0, 10.0]| 16.0|code1|

|    B|13.0|[13.0, 10.0000000]| 13.0|code3|
|    A|57.2|[58.0, 58.0, 28.0]| 58.0|code3|
+-----+----+------------------+-----+-----+
```

**Getting error :**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`code3`' given input columns: [class, mean, count, percentiles];;
```

**How to fix this error and get the desired output ??
what wrong i am doing here and what is the fix here ?**

Comment: There are several errors in your code, but first -- how is `interestedCols` defined and where? I don't think you want to use `reduce()` for those columns here (which are already added above), but you want to just do that `.groupBy` only once on your dataframe, not in a loop. Am I right?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu sorry , updated the question ,  I added the code for List<String> interestedCols = Arrays.asList("code1","code3");  .... for each element  interestedCols I need to perform aggregation mentioned in the code  (i.e. dataAccumlator) , want to get all results at a time in final dataset ... how to do it ?

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu any more information you need ? please let me know

Comment: Your accumulator function should be able to accept as input whatever it emits as output, as it's going to be invoked again and again with its own output. So you can't put your `groupBy` in there (which changes the entire structure of that dataframe) but just add columns or something similar. Keep the `groupBy` for the very end, and only invoke that once.

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu at the end you mean in reducer side ? Can you please give some psedo code in this case please .. me bit confused.

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu   any clue on how to handle this in map in UDF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas